# Read blockwise bytes from binary file in C

Tags: c, file, binary

I need to read a binary file byte for byte in blocks of 8 bytes. Then I need to check bytes 5 and byte 7 whether their value is zero. If it found a block with that criteria, printf should show me the entire 8 byte block.
Sounds pretty easy, but I didn't get it to work as I expected.

I tried something like that, but without success:

```
    unsigned char buffer[8];
    FILE *file;
unsigned long fileLen;

//Open file
file = fopen("tcpstream-noframe.raw", "rb");
if (!file)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", "tcpstream-noframe.raw");
    return 1;
}

for(int i=0; i++ ; i<9999) {
fread(buffer, 8, 1, file);
if(buffer[5] == 0 && buffer[7] == 0)
    printf("%X %X %X %X %X %X %X %X\n",buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2],  buffer[3],buffer[4], buffer[5], buffer[6], buffer[7]);
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: what do you want with `for(int i=0; i++; i<9999)`? Wouldn't you rather change it to `for(int i=0; i<9999; i++)`?

Comment: Define 'without success'. There isn't nearly enough information here to anwer. What output were you expecting, with what in the input file, and what did you get instead?

Comment: What's not working as expected? In what way?

Comment: buff[5] == 6th buffer and buff[7] == 8th buffer so you probably want buff[4] == 0 and buff[6] == 0 additional to the change of the for loop statement.

Comment: @Bort Byte 5 != 5th byte. Byte 5 is, in my understanding, `buff[5]`, whihe 5th byte would be `buff[4]`.

Comment: the indizes are correct, as I count byte0 to byte7. The syntax of the for loop was wrong. Embarrassing.

Comment: you can [read more than one block at a time](https://gist.github.com/5e1ebd3feddf008c0ea7) and get rid of the `9999` magic number.

Comment: or [using a flat char buffer](https://gist.github.com/6e771584e41d37ac8367)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for cycle has no effect. The correct syntax for for cycle is

```
for (initialization_expression;loop_condition;increment_expression){
    // statements
}
```

,which means that you probably switched loop_condition (i<9999) and increment_expression (i++).
Also, if you want to check bytes 5 and 7, in C zero-indexed array you should
check buffer[4] and buffer[6].

Comment: I'm dumb. You're right, the syntax is wrong. The indizes are correct, as I count byte 0 to byte 7.